# How do you set a live video feed as an OpenGL RenderTarget or framebuffer?

Tags: opengl

i would like to take a live video feed from a video camera or 2 to do split screen stuff and render on top of them. How can i capture the input of the video?

i found some old code that uses pbuffers.. is this still the optimal way of doing it?

i guess their is a lot that depends on the connection interface, whether it is USB or fire wire or whatever?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) has an abstraction layer that can handle web/video cameras.